# Weird problems with ef core when filter is applied

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a very weird problem. I have noticed that this problem is caused only when a filter is applied. (check comments in the code for more info)

Stack trace:
[image]
Code:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm)) // If that pass only then i got exception!
{
    query = query.Where(FilterBySearchTerm2(searchTerm));
}

var count = await query.CountAsync(); // here is the exception
var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)Pagination.DefaultPageSize);
```

-- Filter method

```
private Expression<Func<User, bool>> FilterBySearchTerm(string searchTerm)
{
    return u => u.FirstName.Contains(searchTerm, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
        || u.MiddleName.Contains(searchTerm, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
        || u.LastName.Contains(searchTerm, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
        || u.FullName.Contains(searchTerm, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) // FullName is NotMapped property in the User class!
        || u.Company.Name.Contains(searchTerm, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
        || u.Company.Email.Contains(searchTerm, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
        || u.Company.Address.Contains(searchTerm, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
        || u.Company.IncorporationNumber.Contains(searchTerm, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
        || u.Company.DirectorFullName.Contains(searchTerm, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
        || u.Company.DirectorEmail.Contains(searchTerm, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
        || u.Company.DirectorPhone.Contains(searchTerm, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
        || u.Phone.Contains(searchTerm, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
        || u.Email.Contains(searchTerm, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
        || u.Company.CompanyPrograms.Any(cp => cp.Program.Name.Contains(searchTerm, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
        }
```

-- FullName property in User class

```
 [NotMapped]
 public string FullName => string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.MiddleName) ?
      $"{this.LastName} {this.FirstName}" :
      $"{this.LastName} {this.FirstName} {this.MiddleName}";
```

That seems to be very deep in entity framework core, but I don't know if that's a bug or its expected to work like that.

**UPDATE**
I have tested with simpler expression and I found the following:

Don't work:

```
 return u => u.FirstName.Contains(searchTerm, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Work:

```
 return u => u.FirstName.Contains(searchTerm)
```

Work:

```
 return u => u.FullName.Contains(searchTerm)
```

Don't work:

```
return u => u.FirstName.Contains(searchTerm) 
     || u => u.MiddleName.Contains(searchTerm)
     || u => u.LastName.Contains(searchTerm) 
     || u => u.FullName.Contains(searchTerm)
```

Comment: Ugh, that's a horrible filter! Anyway, if a property is not mapped, you cannot use it in the expression if you are using that expression to send to Entity Framework. EF will try to convert it to SQL and, obviously it can't. My advice would be to create a small filter and see if it works, then add properties one by one until it fails.

Comment: The call stack shows a huge mix of LINQ, Ix.NET and your own code. Remove Ix.NET for starters. That huge expression is a big problem in itself though. `Contains` maps to `LIKE '%...%'` which *can't* use any indexes.

Comment: Oh, and also please don't post images of error message or code, copy and paste those into the question.

Comment: Plus, there's a huge risk that this code never runs in the database. EF Core before 3.0 will try to evaluate on the *client* anything that can't be converted to SQL. It's quite possible that EF Core pulled all rows and tried to filter them on the client as LINQ to Objects. Somewhere along the line Ix.NET got involved as well

Comment: `AsyncEnumerable`? That's only available in .NET Core 3.0. What runtime are you targeting?

Comment: Ah, good spot @Pana! (is that a valid short form of your name, or is it Pan? Or maybe Panos?)

Comment: I'm targetting .net core 2.2! Actually, I have found what causes this error, it's because of the second argument in Contains method (StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) and FullName.

Comment: But the more weird thing is if that expression contains only FullName, it works!, if FullName is combined plus some of the other names, it doesn't!

Comment: And if u say that this is a horrible filter? Could you suggest how to improve it?

Comment: Two things: 1. if Full name is important, turn it into a [computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/computed-columns) so it can be incorporated into a SQL statement. 2. Don't use `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` because it triggers [client-side evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval). The database collation is likely to be case-insensitive anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to try to explain it as simple as i can..

First, please make sure that the values you are applying the filter to are not `null`.

Because if you try to call a function over a `null` value such an exception would be thrown.

E.g:

```cs
var keyword = "some key word";
string firstName = "John";
string lastName = null;

if(firstName.contains(keyword, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)){
     //No exception would be thrown,
     //because it is like "john".contains("some key word", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
}


if(lastName.contains(keyword, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)){
     //An exception would be thrown,
     //because it is like null.contains("some key word", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
}
```

The reason why `FullName` works is that because it is a combination of (FirstName, MiddleName, and LastName) and i am sure it is `space-separated` so the `FullName` would never be `null`, if all the combined propitiates are null it would be like .

**Update:**

```cs
string firstName = null;
string lastName = null;
var fullName = $"{firstName} {lastName}"; //or fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;

if(fullName.contains(keyword, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)){
     //No exception would be thrown,
     //because it is like "  ".contains("some key word", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
}
```

---

Update:
**Note:** IMO you do not need to apply the filter to (FirstName, MiddleName, and LastName) because their values are within the `FullName` so you can remove the check condition for those and keep `FullName` with the rest of the filter.

Comment: Yeah, but why removing FullName from expression still works? If FullName is present in expression - exception, if not - no exception! Lol, that's weird.
Okay, I have removed FullName and swapped Contains with EF.Function.Like method and for now it works, but I was curious why this is happening. (See my comments on the first post)

Comment: Probably it is because one of the value is `null`. can you please make sure that all the propitiates you are checking in your db are not null? Also can you provide us with the way you are setting the FullName?.

Comment: I have updated my post. Also in db there is only one row with MiddleName set to `null`, but still it doesn't matter because your example is true in plain c#, but not in an expression tree.

Comment: Check the first post, added examples of what work and what not to understand me better.

Comment: I have tested it on a similar code, and the only way i could get such an exception is when i have null values in my db. If you can test your expression by adding a `not null check` before the `contains` and see if there is any exception would be thrown or not. e.g.: `return u =>  u.FirstName != null && u.FirstName.Contains(searchTerm, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)`.

Comment: Maybe the null was the problem, I'm not really sure, but it doesn't matter already cuz I have fixed it using EF.Like function instead.

Comment: Glad that you fixed it :D.